# Javascript: Split blocks from a string with HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I tried to split a block of string from a string with HTML tags.
My input is

```
var data = '<html>
   <body>

      <div class="test">
         <input type="text"/>
      </div>

      <div class="test">
         <input type="text"/>
      </div>

      <div class="test2">
         <input type="text"/>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>'
```

My excepted output is

```
  '<div class="test">
     <input type="text"/>
  </div>

  <div class="test">
     <input type="text"/>
  </div>'
```

I tried this

```
data.split('<div class="test">');
```

Comment: what about `test2`? you want to skip it?

Comment: Yes i want skip test2

Comment: Don't parse HTML manually. Use native DOM methods

Comment: @Jothimani Have a look at the answer posted by rayon below. That is the right way for doing it. You want it as string or elements?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `dummy div` element. `innerHTML` the `data` in `div`. You can select class elements from `div` using `getElementsByClassName`

```js
var data = '<html>\
   <body>\
      <div class="test">\
         <input type="text"/>\
      </div>\
      <div class="test">\
         <input type="text"/>\
      </div>\
      <div class="test2">\
         <input type="text"/>\
      </div>\
   </body>\
</html>'
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = data;
var classes = div.getElementsByClassName('test');
console.log(classes);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** If you want it as a `string`, you can iterate `collection` returned by `getElementsByClassName`, push it in `array` and `Array#join` it.

```js
var data = '<html>\
   <body>\
      <div class="test">\
         <input type="text"/>\
      </div>\
      <div class="test">\
         <input type="text"/>\
      </div>\
      <div class="test2">\
         <input type="text"/>\
      </div>\
   </body>\
</html>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = data;
var classes = div.getElementsByClassName('test');
var arr = [];
[].forEach.call(classes, function(elem) {
  arr.push(elem.outerHTML);
});
console.log(arr.join(''));
console.log('==============OR===============');
var div2 = document.createElement('div');
[].forEach.call(classes, function(elem) {
  div2.appendChild(elem.cloneNode(true));
});
console.log(div2.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dear Rayon Thanks, i want it as string

Comment: I got the first element 'test', but i need all elements with class 'test'